# how can I add photos from an external drive to the new Photos

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I have a large library of old photos stored on my External Hard Drive (EHD). I would like t bring these old photos into Photos (Mac OS X Yosemite). How can I do this, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: This depends on whether you want to keep them where they are (on the external drive) or copy them to your main hard drive for Photos to manage. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Photos app, go File -> Import, and navigate to the folder with the photos.

If the photos can't be imported using the Import feature in Photos and are in an iPhoto library, you could first open the library with iPhoto, go File -> Export, and export the originals. They could then be imported using the Photos app.